# Can an Android app present itself as a (virtual) Matter device?

Tags: google-smart-home

Is it possible to create an Android app that presents itself as a Matter device? e.g. a thermometer. Any sample code?

Comment: That's an interesting question. Some problems I can see from the Matter spec is the fact that such an app will need to go through certification process and get CD. It will also need DAC+PAI. And this is before we are even talking about the actual Android support for it.

Answer (score 0):

An android app probably can’t do this, as it cannot stay on and listen to external communications on demand all the time. You can look for solutions to run a local server on the android system and implement a virtual device that way.