# How to use an android device as a matter sensor?

Tags: android, google-smart-home

I have an android device running a custom ROM and self-developed apps.

Android version: 8.1 (API level 27)

There is a temperature and humidity sensor built into the android device. Now I want to feed the sensor data into my smart home system using Matter.

I´m not familiar with C++ and other languages apart from Java/Kotlin and Python. So is there any way to send the sensor data to my Amazon Echo Smart Home Hub via the Android software with Matter?

It would also be good if it could work independently of the Smart Home system (Google, Apple, Samsung, etc.).

I have checked out the [Matter Github repository](https://github.com/project-chip/connectedhomeip). There are some example apps and I tried to apply it to my issue. But I did not get any further at this point.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you want the android app to be a Matter device. I'm not sure if it can. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74449664/can-an-android-app-present-itself-as-a-virtual-matter-device

Answer (score 1):

An android app might not be the best path for this, as it cannot stay on and listen to external communications all the time. You can look for solutions to run a local server on the android system and implement a virtual device that way. Also, you can download the matter specification from the CSA website https://csa-iot.org/all-solutions/matter/ and take a look at how to implement matter communications.